# .net Core - Background process

Tags: scheduled-tasks, background-process

I would like to know what is the best approuch to background tasks. For example, I need to send a file to my controller on backend and then I need to run some methods.. but in the same time.. I need to redirect user to another page while this file is processing.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to run background jobs. If you're developing on Azure you could use an Azure webjob or Azure functions. .Net Core 2.0 allows you to schedule background jobs ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/)). The last possibility has a few downsides, but that's all explained in the included article.